# If you pass a scanner as a parameter, will its state be passed as well?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner reading from a text file. When it gets to a certain line in the file, I want to be able to call a method that uses the Scanner as a parameter in its current state - as in, I want the scanner to be passed (along with the file used) at exactly what line it's on.

```
public static void createEntry(File list, int mediaTypeNum, String mediaType) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner mediaReader = new Scanner(list);
    int occurrence = mediaTypeNum;
    int scannerCounter = 0;
    String match;
    String title = "";
    String director = "";
    while (mediaReader.hasNext() && scannerCounter < occurrence) {
        match = mediaReader.nextLine();
        if (match.equalsIgnoreCase(mediaType)) {
            scannerCounter++;
            if (scannerCounter == occurrence) {
                // based on type, create the media object
                // createMediaObject(list, mediaReader, mediaType)
                title = mediaReader.nextLine();
                director = mediaReader.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

createMediaObject() will have a switch case, and based on the case, the Scanner will read some following lines until there's a blank line. For each media type, the number of lines differ.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I only read the title: You are not really passing a `Scanner`, you are passing a reference to that `Scanner`. That means, there is only one `Scanner`, and passing a reference to it won't change it's state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, it is in fact true to any object in Java. No implicit copies of objects are created at any point.*

What you have to be careful about is that `Scanner` has a "sequential" state and if you're passing it around a lot, it's very easy to lose track of what state it is in. Especially if conditional processing is performed, where different execution paths might end up leaving it at different positions.

A good approach to this is to always document in the method Javadoc what state the `Scanner` is expected to be in and what state it's left at the end.

*There's a big caveat to that statement: multithreading. But it would be highly off topic to discuss that here in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You pass the reference to the Scanner object so the receiver sees the same instance and the same state.